# Chamilo ERROR : Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /srv/disk8/1265300/www/portal.mdg-5.org/index.php on line 9

Tags: php, session

I have the following error with my Chamilo

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in
>   /srv/disk8/1265300/www/portal.mdg-5.org/index.php on line 9
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting
>   T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in
>   /srv/disk8/1265300/www/portal.mdg-5.org/index.php on line 9

On line 9 is the following code:

```
use \ChamiloSession as Session;
```

I'm using PHP 5.2.17.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the code you are using is attempting to use PHP namespaces. Namespaces were only introduced in PHP 5.3 and will not work on your system.

PHP >5.3 is specified as a requirement on [the Chamilo website](http://www.chamilo.org/en/download).

Unfortunately, there is essentially nothing you can do short of upgrading your version of PHP. If you are on shared hosting, this will of course be rather difficult.

Comment: Most shared hosters provide PHP extensions in multiple versions. You should ask the support how to activate a more recent version.

Comment: @GhostGambler Good ones do, yes! But I fear that a host that has 5.2 as the default may not be one of the good guys...